# Array Queue- recompile with -xlint: unchecked/ unsafe operations

Tags: java, queue, unchecked

Probably tons of mistakes, sorry. I'm new to java and I'm having a rather hard time with all the syntax and whatnot. I can't get past this error but I fail to see where it is. I can't even compile because I get the message: "...uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint: unchecked for details"
Help, please.

This is supposed to implement the Queue interface which is pretty much just

```
public boolean enqueue(Item item);
public Item dequeue();
public int size;
public boolean isEmpty();
public boolean isFull();
```

I did try to make it circular but I don't know if I've succeeded. 
I think it's those generics that bring about the problem, i don't know.

```
    public class ArrayQueue<Item> implements Queue<Item> {
    private Item[] q;
    public int N = 0;
    private int tail = 0;
    private int head = 0;

    public ArrayQueue(int capacity) {
    q = (Item[]) new Object [capacity];
    }

    public boolean enqueue(Item item) {
        if (isFull())
            return false;
        q[tail++] = item;

        if(tail == q.length )
            tail = 0;
        N++;
        return true;
    }

    public Item dequeue( ) {
        if (isEmpty( ) )
            return null;
        N--;
        Item headItem = q[head];
        q[head++] = null;
        if(head == q.length )
            head = 0;

        return headItem;
    }



    public int size( ) {
        return N;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return N == q.length;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return N == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an error. You can live with it -  "...uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint: unchecked for details"

Comment: I think you have to implement all the Queue abstract methods

Comment: Yeah, I'm leaving it as is

Comment: Is it a requirement to implement the `Queue<E>` interface? If not, make your own lightweight queue interface. You won't need to worry about generics then. Oh, and you may want to change your class declaration to `public class ArrayQueue implements Queue<Item> {...`

Answer (score 0):

The warning about “unchecked or unsafe operations” should not prevent the code from being compiled. You have to fix the other errors. Note that it is impossible to implement array-based generic collections without getting such warnings (or suppressing them). That’s why it is better to use existing JFC `Collection` implementations as you can expect their developers to be careful and experienced enough to differentiate between unavoidable warnings and real problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, that is just a warning because of one of the casting. you can use one these options:
1- Add        Item[] ts = (Item[])(new Object[CAPACITY]);
        q = ts;
or

2- add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") at the beginning of the class to ignore all warning and see where the error is.